# PHP получение сериализоавнных данных

Tags: php

Я получаю такую строку json

```
t:1:{s:6:"status";s:7:"success";}
```

как мне вытащить status?

```
echo json_decode($data);
```

пустота

Comment: у вас не json, а сериализированный массив: `$str = 'a:1:{s:6:"status";s:7:"success";}';
var_dump(unserialize($str));` Получаем: array(1) { ["status"]=> string(7) "success" }

Answer (score 3):

Ваша строка - не JSON, это сериализованная строка, полученная с помощью команды [`serialize()`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.serialize.php).

```php
var_dump(unserialize($data));
```